# MySQL query wrong COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I’m developing an app. I have to do a query where I see the rooms where I’m guest or admin. That's easy. The problem is that I want to get, at the same time, the number of players inside the same room.

```
SELECT rooms.id, rooms.name, rooms.buyin, rooms.administrator, rooms.creation_date,
       rooms.max_players, rooms.min_players, count(room_players.room)
FROM rooms, room_players
WHERE administrator = 1 and room_players.room = rooms.id
```

I have a table with the rooms and the other (room_players) that is a match between users and rooms. If i delete the `count(room_players.room)` and `and room_players.room = rooms.id` I have the rooms that I’m admin. But I need the number of players inside the same room too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query needs a `group by`.  With the `COUNT()` in the `select`, it becomes an aggregation query that returns one row -- a summary of all the rows in the table.

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.buyin, r.administrator, r.creation_date,
       r.max_players, r.min_players, count(rp.room)
FROM rooms r join
     room_players rp
     ON rp.room = r.id 
WHERE administrator = 1 
GROUP BY r.id;
```

I also fixed the join syntax to be an explicit join and added table aliases to make the query more readable.

EDIT:

I suspect the query you want is something like:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.buyin, r.administrator, r.creation_date,
       r.max_players, r.min_players, count(rp.room)
FROM rooms r join
     room_players rp
     ON rp.room = r.id 
WHERE administrator <> 1 
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING sum(user = 1) > 0;
```

Comment: It did work. Many thanks. I tried to join two queries, but didn't work and I don't know why. I liked your way, it's easier and simple to understand.

Comment: But i have a problem with this, if i want to get the rooms that I'm not admin (only guest), it doesn't counts very well the number of players inside the room.

Comment: @miguelpveloso . . . I don't know what `admin` is.  If it is a column in `room_players`, then you can remove the `where` and after the `group by`:  `having sum(administrator = 1) > 0`.

Comment: `SELECT r.id, r.name, r.buyin, r.administrator, r.creation_date,
       r.max_players, r.min_players, count(rp.room)
FROM rooms r join
     room_players rp
     ON rp.room = r.id 
WHERE administrator != 1 AND rp.user = 1
GROUP BY r.id;`

Is this possible? This doesn't return me the count of players inside the room.

Answer (score 0):

How about subtracting the # of admin from the total users?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to use `GROUP BY` or even, universe-forbid, naming fields the same in different tables.